Grid Items disappearing
I am making a grid and the elements keep disappearing when the screen gets smaller and they don't go to the next row
here is the page.tsx code:
import React from "react";
import { DashboardNavBar } from "@/components/dashboardNavBar";
import CreateButton from "@/components/createProject/createButton";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prisma";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import ProjectCard from "@/components/projectCard";

const DashboardPage = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();
  const projects = await prismadb.presentation.findMany({
    where: {
      userId: userId,
    },
  });
  return (
    <div className="w-full min-h-screen bg-slate-950">
      <div className="pt-3">
        <DashboardNavBar />
      </div>
      <div className="w-full grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-3 px-4 my-10 ">
        <CreateButton />
        {projects.map((project) => (
          <ProjectCard key={project.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardPage;

my projectCard.tsx:

"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ProjectCard = () => {
  const [background, setBackground] = useState("");
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");

  const randomElement = () => {
    const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
    return array[Math.floor(array.length * Math.random())];
  };

  const randomColor = () => {
    let color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += randomElement();
    }
    return color;
  };

  const randomAngle = () => {
    return Math.floor(360 * Math.random());
  };

  const generateBackground = () => {
    const gradientColor1 = randomColor();
    const gradientColor2 = randomColor();
    const newBg =
      "linear-gradient(" +
      randomAngle() +
      "deg, " +
      gradientColor1 +
      ", " +
      gradientColor2 +
      ")";
    setBackground(newBg);
    setCode(newBg);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    generateBackground(); // Call the function when the component mounts
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means it only runs once, on mount

  return (
    <div
      className="w-full h-full mx-5 opacity-40 rounded-3xl"
      style={{ background: background }}
    >
      <div className="h-full bg-gradient-to-b from-transparent to-gray-900 rounded-3xl"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectCard;

and my createNutton.tsx:
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import { Plus } from "lucide-react";
import React from "react";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { formSchema } from "@/components/createProject/constants";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "../ui/input";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";

const CreateButton = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      description: "",
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/create-project", {
        name: values.name,
        description: values.description,
      });

      if (response.status == 200) {
        setOpen(false);
        form.reset();
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
      <DialogTrigger className="rounded-3xl bg-gray-900 flex flex-col  mx-7 items-center p-10 shadow-gradient-right transition duration-200 ease-in-out hover:shadow-gradient-right-hover">
        <Plus className="h-[50px] w-[50px] text-gray-50" />
        <span className="font-xs text-gray-50 pt-3">New</span>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            This action cannot be undone. This will permanently delete your
            account and remove your data from our servers.
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>

        <Form {...form}>
          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <FormField
              name="name"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                  <FormLabel>Project name</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input placeholder="The life of Shakespeare" {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              name="email"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                  <FormLabel>Project Description</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="This presentation is for literature class"
                      {...field}
                      type="text"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <DialogTrigger asChild>
              <Button type="submit" className="block m-auto my-3">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </DialogTrigger>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default CreateButton;


And I know I am not passing the project to the projectCard still
I tried almost every solution i could find,but nothing made a difference

With pure CSS we use grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);. Check this answer for the Tailwind case.
